# Spring Cloud OAuth2: Password grant type & resource security

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I have two questions regarding [spring-cloud-security](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/) with OAuth2:

1. How do I protected resources by a grant_type? I want to secure my REST API with client_credentials and then want to protected user specific resources by the password grant type. Is this even possible?
2. Accoording to [this](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) tutorial, the password grant type does not need a client secret, though spring cloud oauth2 always seems to require the client secret. How do I handle this? By setting a nonsense client secret like "abc" and just not care about it?
3. If I have a client app with @EnableOAuth2Sso I only get a redirect to the authorization Uri although I dont provide grant type "authorization code". Wouldn't it make more sense if I was redirected to the token Uri if I only provide the password grant type?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I protected resources by a grant_type? I want to secure my REST API with client_credentials

Use an OAuth2 access rule and specify that you want client only. E.g. use the `#oauth2` expression variable and `#oauth2.isClient()` ([source code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java)).

> the password grant type does not need a client secret

Wrong. You need to authenticate the client. If it doesn't have a password it's not very secure, but you can do that (use an empty password) if you want to.

> If I have a client app with @EnableOAuth2Sso I only get a redirect to the authorization Uri although I dont provide grant type "authorization code". Wouldn't it make more sense if I was redirected to the token Uri if I only provide the password grant type?

No, the token endpoint is a back channel and it doesn't work like that (even supposing you allowed tokens to be granted from a GET, what would the user do with the response?). There is no protocol for external web applications to use a password grant (it's primarily for native apps). In a web application you should use the auth code.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Didn't know about the [expression-based access control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html). I now use method security expressions and it works like a charm. Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. Keep on doin' that gerat work!